# How to use import global sass variables with create-react-app (ejected)

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, create-react-app

Please see [this repo](https://github.com/jimmy-e/cra-style-variables) for further information and reproduction.

I am using an ejected create-react-app and I want to be able to use global sass variables in an individual stylesheet without having to import the stylesheet. I think using `sass-resources-loader` is what I should use (although if there is a better way of doing this, please let me know). I have updated the create-react-app ejected webpack config [here](https://github.com/jimmy-e/cra-style-variables/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js#L142-L147), but whenever I run `yarn start`, I still get the complaint:

> SassError: Undefined variable: "$boxSize".
> on line 5 of src/SampleComponent/sampleComponent.scss
> ,   height: $boxSize;

Is there something that I am doing wrong in trying to use `sass-resources-loader` or should I be using something different instead? Thanks, and here are some file snippets below for more context:

**file structure:**

```
src/
  - SampleComponent/
    - SampleComponent.js
    - SampleComponent.scss
  - styles/
    - sizes.scss
  - index.js
```

**SampleComponent.js:**

```js
import * as styles from './sampleComponent.scss';

const SampleComponent = () => (
  <div className={styles.div}>
    <h3>hello world</h3>
  </div>
);

export default SampleComponent;
```

**sampleComponent.scss:**

```css
.div {
  align-items: center;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  height: $boxSize;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5rem;
  width: $boxSize;
}
```

**sizes.scss:**

```css
$boxSize: 30rem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the sass-loader library, I use it that way and it works very well.

```
{
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    additionalData: `
        @import "sources/scss/modules/_config.scss";
        @import "sources/scss/modules/_global.scss";
      `
  },
},
```